# Finding eulerian circuit in an undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory, depth-first-search

Hierholzer's Algorithm helps us to find Eulerian circuit in the graph, if present, in O(m+n) time but it uses an adjacency matrix which takes O(n^2) space. Can someone give an O(m+n) time algorithm which uses depth-first search traversal using adjacency list representation of graph which takes O(m+n) space? Here m represents number of edges and n represents number of vertices in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

An undirected graph has a eulerian circuit if all vertices with non-zero degree are connected and if all vertices are even degree. A degree is defined as the number of edges incident to the vertex (loops are counted twice). An undirected graph has a eulerian path if all vertices with non-zero degree are connected and if two vertices are odd degree and all other vertices have even degree.

To check if your  undirected graph has a Eulerian circuit with an adjacency list representation of the graph, count the number of vertices with odd degree. This is where you can utilize your adjacency list. If the odd count is 0, then check if all the non-zero vertices are connected. You can do this by using DFS traversals. If you traverse through the graph from a starting node and you find that other nodes have not been visited after the traversal ends, your graph must not be connected.  However, if it is connected, then your undirected graph has a Eulerian circuit.